# Calcular Suma en tiempo real con JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Cordial Saludo.

Espero se encuentren bien y me puedan ayudar.

Tengo 2 inputs y al momento de estar digitando, se cambia a un formato de moneda:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input name="N1" type="text"  id="Num1"  class="mis-adicionales">
    <input name="N2" type="text"  id="Num2"  class="mis-adicionales">
    <input name="Res" type="text" id="Res"  disabled="">
```

Eso gracias a las siguientes 2 funciones

```
  $("#Num1").on({
  "focus": function(event) {
    $(event.target).select();
  },
  "keyup": function(event) {
    $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
    });
  }
});

$("#Num2").on({
  "focus": function(event) {
    $(event.target).select();
  },
  "keyup": function(event) {
    $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
    });
  }
});
```

Hasta acá vamos bien.

Lo que deseo hacer ahora, es que ambos se sumen automaticamente y el resultado se muestre en el tercer input,

esto es lo que tengo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

               $(document).on('click keyup','.mis-adicionales',function() {
                 calcular();
               });

            });

          function calcular() {
              var tot = $('#Res');
             // tot = tot.replace(/,/g, "");
              tot.val(0);
              $('.mis-adicionales').each(function() {
                  tot.val(parseFloat(tot.val()) + (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseFloat($(this).val())));
              });
//          var totalParts = parseFloat(tot.val()).toFixed(3).split('0');
//          tot.val('$' + totalParts[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')); 

          var totalParts = parseInt(tot.val()).toFixed(3).split('.');
          tot.val('$' + totalParts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",") + '.' +  (totalParts.length > 1 ? totalParts[1] : ''));  
            }

</script>
```

Quiero resaltar que cuando hay mas de 1 coma "," o mas de 1 punto ".", como que deja de funcionar y no me hace los calculos bien, el tercer input tambien debe quedar como formato moneda.

Espero me puedan ayudar

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ayuda, por favor :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basare mi respuesta suponiendo que `#Num1` y `#Num2` estan correctos como indicas.

Si te fijas, a los input `#Num1` y `#Num2` los separas por puntos(`.`) verdad.

Ahora, en la funcion `calcular` tienes un `foreach` el cual me supongo que estas extrayendo los valores de `#Num1` y `#Num2` (***incluyendo los puntos***).

¿En que momento dentro del `foreach` le dices que elimine los puntos de cada uno de los input?. Nunca lo haces y en cada repeticion el valor devuelto por `$(this).val()` contendra siempre los puntos y cuando le aplicas el `parseFloat` no dara error pero ya el resultado no es el esperado.

Por lo que te sugiero que cada vez que haces `$(this).val()` al valor devuelto le reemplazes los puntos(`.`) de esta forma `$(this).val().replace(/\./g, "")`

Al final tu `foreach` dentro de la funcion `calcular` quedaria asi:

```
$('.mis-adicionales').each(function() {
    tot.val(parseFloat(tot.val()) + (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/\./g, ""))) ? 0 : parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/\./g, ""))));
});
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me has salvado la Vida jaja, Te agradezco mucho